# How replace ignore a Maven module and reference a JAR in VS Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm currently running a multi-modules Maven project in VS Code and I would like to ignore a module in the IDE and use its JAR instead, without modifying the `pom.xml` files.

It's easily achievable on IntelliJ (`Project Structure` > `Modules` > delete the module then go in `Librairies` > `New Project Library` and select the JAR).

Is there something similar achievable under VS Code?

Comment: What is the reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example or describe your problem in detail? What do you expect to achieve? What now?

Comment: @JFabianMeier it's a huge project and this module (legacy stuff that is barely used) takes a long time to compile. To speed up debugging session, it's much faster to ignore this module and use the JAR instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `.jar` package through the plus sign on the right side of **Referenced Libraries** under the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this section doesn't show up, I have a "Maven dependency" instead.

Comment: Use the `mvn` command to install the jar to the local repository, and then add it to the project. There is no direct interface for vscode, you can submit a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new).